# A href's link is changed when I run the project in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a link in my project using this code :

```
<body> 
     <ul>
         @foreach (Menu menu in ViewBag.menu)
         {
             <li>
                 <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
             </li>
         }
     </ul>
 </body>
```

But when I run my project in mvc, the link of this code is change to `http://localhost:2321/www.google.com`.

So how can I remove this part `http://localhost:2321`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify the full link, with protocol; otherwise it is interpreted as if you are trying to access a local object (by relative path):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```